# codeigniter get_where() function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using active record on an old codeigniter installation and I am running into problems executing multiple queries using the get_where function. for instance the following code

```
$this->db->get_Where('activation', array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'));
echo $this->db->last_query();
$this->db->get_Where('users', array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'));
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

the first query generates

```
SELECT * FROM (`activation`) WHERE `email` = 'test@yahoo.com'
```

the second one throws me for a loop and generates

```
SELECT * FROM (`activation`, `users`)
WHERE `email` = 'test@yahoo.com' AND `email` = 'test@yahoo.com'
```

Am i supposed to be clearing something?

Comment: I would change the echo to `echo $this->db->result()` so it ends the query function.

Comment: write `$this>db->free_result();` after `echo`

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->get_Where('activation', array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'))->row();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$this->db->select('*')->where('email','test@yahoo.com')->get('activation')->result()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the results from your query with `$this->db->query->result();`

```
$this->db->get_Where('activation', array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'));
echo $this->db->last_query();
$result_1 = $this->db->query->result();

$this->db->get_Where('users', array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'));
echo $this->db->last_query();
$result_2 = $this->db->query->result();
```

or if you want to return an array use `result_array();` instead of `result();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->get_Where('activation', array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'));
echo $this->db->last_query();
$result_1 = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

this will execute the first query 
 and then

```
$this->db->get_Where('users', array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'));
echo $this->db->last_query();
$result_2 = $this->db->get()->result();
```

this will execute the second query then u can do below code to print the two results

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($result_1);print_r($result_2);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple get_where statements in same function then it will be concatenated.
So Better use a condition for those two conditions to execute a single query at a time.
For example,

```
if(//condition 1)
{
$query=$this->db->get_Where('activation', array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'));     
}
else{
$query=$this->db->get_Where('users', array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'));
}
//finally get the active record.
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Otherwise you wont achieve.
**Please mention the purpose to get two table records.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it like this:

```
$this->db->get_where('users', array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'))->result();
```

Well apart from using get_where you can simply use it like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('activation');
$this->db->where('email','test@yahoo.com');
or
$this->db->where(array('email'=>'test@yahoo.com'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->db->get_where($table, $where, $limit, $offset)

$where  = array('FIELD_NAME'=>value)

result_array();
```